# SparseTensor equivalent of tf.tile?

Tags: tensorflow

There's a [tf.tile](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.10/api_docs/python/array_ops.html#tile) function, which takes a tensor and copies it a given number of times.

```
f = tf.tile([5], [3])
f.eval() == array([3, 3, 3], dtype=int32)
```

How to achieve something similar with `SparseTensor`s:

```
g = tf.SparseTensorValue([[0, 0]], values=[5], shape=[1, 1])
tiled = tf.tile(g, [10, 1]) <- gives ValueError: Argument must be a dense tensor
```

?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, I have found a solution (that works on `SparseTensor`s, but not on `SparseTensorValue`s):

```
tiled = tf.sparse_concat(0, [g] * 10)
```